# Where is this mountain quote in the Sinhala edition?

Tags: tipitaka

I am comparing translations to see how the Sinhala would work, and, granted I am using Google Translate on the Sinhala version, I would at least expect it to be generally somewhat reflective of what is being said. But it doesn't say what I am looking for.

I am looking for this quote [here](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.3.04.than.html) or [here](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/thag/thag.14.01.than.html):

```
As a mountain of rock
is unwavering, well-settled,
so a monk whose delusion is ended
doesn't quiver —
just like a mountain.
```

However what I find in the Sinhala version [here](https://www.thripitakaya.org/tipitakaya/Index/653?s=21249) or [here](https://www.thripitakaya.org/tipitakaya/Index/828?s=22245) is this:

> "Just as a gal can stand steady, so the brain will not be a sin in the mind."

Or

> The stanza is so immovable that it does not become immovable.

I am just picking pieces that appear close in the same area of text. Does one know if these translations in Sinhala are accurate? (And that it's just a *major* Google translate issue). Does that quote exist somewhere in the Sinhala?

I am trying to make do snippets of translation myself and am looking for a good example of interesting quotes. If one could paste the quote in Sinhala that would be amazing.

Or is this just an example of a translator taking "poetic expression" to the extreme, and they just took a general quote like "යම්සේ ගල්පව්වෙක් අචල වැ මොනොවට පිහිටියේ ද, එසේ ම මහණ තෙම මොහය ක්ෂීණ වීමෙන් පව්වක් මෙන් ‍නො සැලේ.", which Google translates as "Even if a galvanist is immobile, the loss of his brain will not be a sin.", and they just made up a poetic metaphor to translate it into English?

Comment: ChrisW is correct. But it's not lust. It's illusion or delusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that https://suttacentral.net/ud3.4/si/zoysa is the Sinhala version of Ud3.4 on suttacentral.

Google Translate translates the last sentence of that into English as follows ...

> නොසෙල් වෙන්නාවූ මනාව පිහිටියාවූ ගල් පර්වතය යම්සේද එසේ මෝහය නැතිකර දැමූ භික්‍ෂුව පර්වතයක් මෙන් කම්පා නොවෙයි.
>
> Like a well-formed rock, the monk who loses his lust does not shake like a rock.

The Pali says,

> Yathāpi pabbato selo,
> acalo suppatiṭṭhito;
> Evaṃ mohakkhayā
> bhikkhu,
> pabbatova na vedhatī”ti.

... which I think says, "destruction of ignorance" (i.e. [Moha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moha_(Buddhism))) or "delusion" -- not "lust".

Comment: I'm Sinhala native from Sri Lanka and this is nearly accurate. Like a well-formed rock, the monk who loses his lust does not shake like a rock. Here mohaya means not lust. It's illusion or delusion.

Answer (score 3):

> As a mountain of rock is unwavering, well-settled, so a monk whose
>   delusion is ended doesn't quiver — just like a mountain.
>
> ශෛලපර්වතය තෙම යම් සේ අචල ද මොනවට පිහිටියේ වේ ද එපරිද්දෙන් මොහක්ෂය
>   හෙතුකොටගෙන පර්වතයක් මෙන් (අචල) වූ මහණ තෙම නො සැලේ.

This is the correct sinhala translation for the quote that you originally mentioned in your question. I picked that from the second link where you found the sinhala version. Unfortunately, google translation not works for both sides. The above sentences also a little bit different when translating, but the meaning is perfectly correct.

Comment: Can we remove the stuff in the parentheses? Because they didn't have parentheses back then.

Comment: Yes. we can remove the stuff in parentheses. meaning for අචල is  'not moving' or 'steady'. it is a further explanation for behaviour of rock.